# Android : How can I know how much memory is allocated on VM for my app?

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, heap-memory, dalvik

I'm an android developer from Korea.

I have to perform some tests about space-complexity in case of high object allocation & deallocation.

So, I want to measure how much memory is allocated on VM for my app. **NOT A WHOLE DEVICE OR WHOLE APP'S ALLOCATED MEMORY BUT MY APP ONLY!!**

Yes. I already know that there is an Android built-in ActivityManager.getMemoryInfo()

But I'm confused: getMemoryInfo() has some attributes.

long availMem , long totalMem ...

Are these for the whole device? or for my app?
And is there another method to get these stuff?

Does anybody know about that?
Please help me.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 5):

There is simple method.
just use Debug.MemoryInfo().
codes are same as followings

```
Debug.MemoryInfo memInfo = new Debug.MemoryInfo ();
Debug.getMemoryInfo ( memInfo );

memInfo.getTotalPss (); 
// Indicates Proportional Set Size. USS + (SharedPage/Number of Shared Page) 

memInfo.getPrivateDirty ();
// Memory should to be freed.
```

That's all!